# What's the difference between require.config and requirejs.config

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to set up requirejs and then optimise it using r.js, but then I'm confuse with these method. I've used require.config() before, but then I saw they also have requirejs.config() and I don't know what's the difference. Sample code:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    paths: {
        app: '../app'
    }
});

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    paths: {
        app: '../app'
    }
});
```

They both do the same thing. And when I optimise it, the result is exactly the same. I want to know what's the difference? When should I use on or the other?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

"requirejs" is just an alias to the same API, since "require" is used by other libraries. From [the documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/1.0/docs/api.html#jsfiles):

> If you just want to load some JavaScript files, use the require() API. If there is already a require() in the page, you can use requirejs() to access the RequireJS API for loading scripts.

Even though it makes no technical difference, just by convention I would stay with require.config unless you have a naming conflict with some other module loader.

Results as of 6-Jun-2013:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=require.config (609 results)

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=requirejs.config (258 results)